# Add Conditions for connecting with a second sortable list

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Problem:** I'm unsure how to add the condition of

"if("Are you sure" is answered with "ok") to only apply to across list sorting".

**logic:** if item is moved from list1 to list2 then alert("Are you sure"), else if item is moved from list1 to list1 OR list2 to list2 then do nothing(other then sort that item to it's new spot in the list).

```js
$(".sortable1").sortable({
 update: function (event, ui) {
    if (!confirm("Are you sure?")) {
         event.preventDefault();
            }
        },
connectWith: ".sortable2"
});

$(".sortable2").sortable({connectWith: ".sortable1"});
```

```css
.sortable1{
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px black;
 float: left;
 width: 35%;
 list-style: none;
 margin-right: 5%;
}

.sortable2{
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px black;
 float: left; 
 width: 35%;
 list-style: none;
}

li{ 
padding: 0; 
margin: 0;
box-shadow: .25px .25px .25px .25px black;
text-align: center;
}

ul{
padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<ul class="list  sortable1">
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
</ul>

<ul class="list  sortable2">
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to extend your `update()` handler to check the source and drop zone of the item being dragged to decide if a confirmation should be shown. A quick way to do this is with:

```
/* Is item being dragged from sortable1 ? */
$(event.target).hasClass('sortable1')
```

And:

```
/* If item being droped in sortable2 ? */
$(ui.item).closest('.sortable2').length > 0
```

With these two building blocks, you can achieve the required behaviour as follows:

```
$(".sortable1").sortable({
  update: function(event, ui) {

    /* If drag event trigged from item in sortable1? */
    if ($(event.target).hasClass('sortable1')) {

      /* And item drop zone in sortable2? */
      if ($(ui.item).closest('.sortable2').length > 0) {

        /* Then ask user for confirmation */
        if (!confirm("Are you sure?")) {
          event.preventDefault();
        }
      }
    }
  },
  connectWith: ".sortable2"
});

$(".sortable2").sortable({
  connectWith: ".sortable1"
});
```

A working example can be see in the snippet below:

```js
$(".sortable1").sortable({
  update: function(event, ui) {
    
    /* If drag event trigged from item in sortable1? */
    if ($(event.target).hasClass('sortable1')) {
    
      /* And item drop zone in sortable2? */
      if ($(ui.item).closest('.sortable2').length > 0) {
        
        /* Then ask user for confirmation */
        if (!confirm("Are you sure?")) {
          event.preventDefault();
        }
      }
    }
  },
  connectWith: ".sortable2"
});

$(".sortable2").sortable({
  connectWith: ".sortable1"
});
```

```css
.sortable2, .sortable1 {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px black;
  float: left;
  width: 35%;
  list-style: none;
}

.sortable1 {
  margin-right: 5%;
}

li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-shadow: .25px .25px .25px .25px black;
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<ul class="list sortable1">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>

<ul class="list sortable2">
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
</ul>
```